# Change :hover with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `<ul>` tag that shows some of the `<li>` on hover. It works well in `HTML`. Now, I want to change that with `jQuery`. I want to NOT show the `<li>` `#two` and `#three` on hover. I tried to prevent the default behaviour with `e.preventDefault();` but it does not work.

How can I change `:hover` with jQuery? In other words, I want #two and #three to hide on hoover only with jquery

I have it to check here: https://jsfiddle.net/42jqt4pn/2/

```js
$("#language").mouseenter(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
#language #two,
#language #three {
  display: none;
}
#language:hover #two,
#language:hover #three {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="language">
  <li id="one"><a href="#">en</a>
  </li>
  <li id="two"><a href="#">ca</a>
  </li>
  <li id="three"><a href="#">fr</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please explain in full detail the behavior you are looking for. Broken code is not a good substitute for a proper explanation

Comment: Mouseenter is NOT cancelable. You can't prevent its default. https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-mouseenter

Comment: why can't you just change the css and remove the hover rule?

Comment: @charlietfl progressive enhancement. I try to make the basic when javascript is disabled and then make a better design when javascript is enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with jQuery's `.hover()` method:

```js
$("#language").hover(function() {
  $("#two").css("display", "none");
  $("#three").css("display", "none");
}, function() {});
```

```css
#language #two,
#language #three {
  display: none;
}
#language:hover #two,
#language:hover #three {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="language">
  <li id="one"><a href="#">en</a>
  </li>
  <li id="two"><a href="#">ca</a>
  </li>
  <li id="three"><a href="#">fr</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why do you need script to hide #3 when it is hidden by the css?

Comment: That's a question for OP lol.. incredible to be downvoted. I simply provide an answer to his scenario.

Comment: Not incredible at all...when the answer doesn't make sense

Comment: Why do you use two hover(function() ?

Answer (score 2):

> progressive enhancement. I try to make the basic when javascript is disabled and then make a better design when javascript is enabled

One way to do this is to set a class attribute on the `body` that you *remove* with javaScript. This way you know if the visitor has JS enabled and can style it accordingly. Simply prefix all your 'no-js' styles with the `.no-js` classname.

```js
//if the user has JS enabled, remove the no-js classname:
$("body").removeClass("no-js");
```

```css
#language #two,
#language #three {
  display: none;
}
/* the following rule is only applied when the no-js class is set on the body */
.no-js #language:hover #two,
.no-js #language:hover #three {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="no-js">
<ul id="language">
  <li id="one"><a href="#">en</a>
  </li>
  <li id="two"><a href="#">ca</a>
  </li>
  <li id="three"><a href="#">fr</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just toggle a class on the element and modify the css to account for that class

```
$("#language").hover(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('active')
});
```

CSS

```
#language #two, #language.active:hover #two
#language #three, #language.active:hover #three {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Why would he touch CSS to later add jQuery when he can solve it straight from CSS with `#language:hover #two, #language:hover #three {
 display:none;
}`? Note the "only with jQuery" part, don't worry I won't downvote anyways.

Comment: where do you put the class  active in the css?

Comment: look at the modifed css in answer, it's right there